# Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Promise<KindeUser | null>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, authentication, next.js

I'm working on a chat with PDF document project utilizing '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server' for authentication. While attempting to access the 'email' property from the user object obtained through 'getKindeServerSession().getUser()', I encountered the error 'Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Promise<KindeUser | null>'.

Here's the code snippet where the issue arises:

```
**typescript:**
import { getKindeServerSession } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import React from 'react';

const Page = async () => {
    const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
    const user = getUser();

    if (!user || !user.id) redirect('/auth-callback?origin=dashboard');

    // Now trying to display the email but encountering the error
    return (
        <div>
            {user.email}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

I've attempted to access the email property of the user obtained from Kinde using the code snippet:

```
import { getKindeServerSession } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import React from 'react'

const Page = async () => {
    const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession()
    const user = getUser()

    if (!user || !user.id) redirect('/auth-callback?origin=dashboard')

    // Attempting to display the email but encountering the error
    return (
        <div>
            {user.email}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Page
```

Comment: `getUser()` returns a promise. So, you need to use `await` with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced with same problem today, it looks like difference between NextJS App Router v1 & v2, your implementation is using v2 which could not get user for some reason. by following documentation [here](https://kinde.com/docs/developer-tools/nextjs-sdkv1/) added await: `return await handleAuth(request, endpoint);` on *src/app/api/auth/[kindeAuth]/route.js*.

you need to add await like following:

```
const {getUser} = getKindeServerSession();
const user = await getUser();
```